# Transitive dependency with spring projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-test-mvc

I have two spring web applications A and B. Here B needs some of the methods in A application to be successful.

However, A being a seperate project, loads all of its bean in its spring xml when container starts. Though I added project dependency of A in project B through eclipse, I get error while loading project B saying bean instances of A not found.

Please advise how can this be resolved. I tried adding maven dependencies as well.

Comment: Create a "common" project C and make A and B use C as a dependency? What do you mean by "Here B needs some of **the methods** in A" (there's no *flying* method in java)?

Comment: A has some set of services already defined and B needs to use them for its processing. Again, if C is a common project between A and B, what is the best way A communicates to C?

Comment: As said, A is a spring application. Assume it has class EmployeeService with multiple properties and has method sortNames. So basically EmployeeService bean will be successful only when its spring-xml file loads successfully. My Question is if I use a Common Project C how can i ensure that using EmployeeService will be instantiated by loading its XML files.

Comment: If C is a dependency (as in maven dependency), there's no communication just "usage". Maybe you should add code for the `sortNames` method you want to reuse (if that's what you need)

Comment: can you please elaborate on C being maven dependency. I am confused.